# Generate audio graph from 3gpp

Tags: android, audio, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm writing audio recorder as part of application which has audio graph as well. For recording and showing live audio graph it was pretty easy, just call MediaRecorder.GetMaxAmplitude() every X ms and based on that update canvas which represents the audio graph.

The problem - I want to have same audio graph when one of the recording is opened, so now I can't use .GetMaxAmplitude() method since I would need to fully play the recording to generate the graph, which would take too much time and is just silly.

If recording output would be .wav, it would be pretty straightforward, lots of material out where how to do it, however MediaRecorder doesn't support .wav and I don't really want embed full ffmpeg with wrapper to my app just for this small functionality to decode 3gpp into wav.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `MediaExtractor` and `MediaCodec` you can decode your `3gp` (or any other supported mime type) into a series of PCM-16bit (mime `audio/raw`) buffers and from that you can subsample to obtain your desired amplitude graph at a "graphable" sampling rate.

This is an example using synchronous processing on the input/output buffer so run it on non-UI thread.

#### Synchronous PCM-16bit `MediaCodec` Example:

```
var file = new Java.IO.File(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DirectoryDownloads), "someaudiofile.mp3");
if (file.CanRead())
{
    var mediaExtractor = new MediaExtractor();
    mediaExtractor.SetDataSource(file.ToString());
    mediaExtractor.SelectTrack(0); // which track? lets assume single/mono for this example
    var mediaFormat = mediaExtractor.GetTrackFormat(0);
    var mime = mediaFormat.GetString(MediaFormat.KeyMime);
    var mediaCodec = MediaCodec.CreateDecoderByType(mime);
    mediaCodec.Configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodecConfigFlags.None);
    mediaCodec.Start();
    var bufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
    var inputDone = false;
    while (true)
    {
        if (!inputDone) // process input stream and queue it up for output processing
        {
            int inputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.DequeueInputBuffer(10000);
            if (inputBufferIndex >= 0)
            {
                var inputBuffer = mediaCodec.GetInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex);
                int chunkSize = mediaExtractor.ReadSampleData(inputBuffer, 0);
                Log.Debug("SO", $"Input Buffer: {inputBufferIndex}");
                if (chunkSize <= 0)
                {
                    mediaCodec.QueueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, 0, 0L, MediaCodecBufferFlags.EndOfStream);
                    inputDone = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    mediaCodec.QueueInputBuffer(inputBufferIndex, 0, chunkSize, mediaExtractor.SampleTime, MediaCodecBufferFlags.None);
                    mediaExtractor.Advance();
                }
            }
        }

        int outputBufferIndex = mediaCodec.DequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, 1000000);
        if (outputBufferIndex >= 0)
        {
            Log.Debug("SO", $"Output Buffer: {outputBufferIndex}");
            if (bufferInfo.Size != 0)
            {
                var outputBuffer = mediaCodec.GetOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex); // PCM 16-bit output
                var outpuFormat = mediaCodec.GetOutputFormat(outputBufferIndex);
                outputBuffer.Position(0);
                // !!! Sub-sample the buffer based upon your needed sampling rate for display
                var pcm16bitBuffer = outputBuffer.AsShortBuffer();
                while (pcm16bitBuffer.HasRemaining)
                {
                    var x = pcm16bitBuffer.Get();
                    // store the prior values and avg./max/... them for later display based upon some subsampling rate
                }
                pcm16bitBuffer.Dispose();
                mediaCodec.ReleaseOutputBuffer(outputBufferIndex, false);
                if (bufferInfo.Flags.HasFlag(MediaCodecBufferFlags.EndOfStream))
                    break;
            }
            else
                break;
        }
        else if (outputBufferIndex == -2)
        {
            Log.Debug("SO", "Output buffer is not available yet, feed more input");
        }
    }
    mediaCodec.Stop();
    mediaCodec.Release();
}
```

Note: There are asynchronous methods available also, consult the `MediaCodec` docs for Android API levels for what is available for your app's targeted audience.

#### Output sample using the above method:

[image]

Re: [MediaCodec](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec.html)

Comment: Sorry for late response, but thanks! This is my first time working with audio processing so I got a bit overhelmed. One other thing tho, how would I got applying sampling rate to this? Just take element from the list, skipping {Sample rate} of elements after?

Comment: @EdgarasAusvicas You could just skip X number of samples, this might present weird glitches in the graph, or create a moving average of the peak output and then take one sample of the average every X samples (I would lean towards that), but in the end it depends upon how accurate you need the graph to look to the waveform.